# If statements running at the same time how to

Tags: python, if-statement

```
if input("Raining? ") == "yes":
    print("Then you should take an umbrella")

if input("Raining? ") == "no":
    print("Then you should not take an umbrella ")
```

so I want these 2 to check yes or no at the same time so when I type no the printed answer should be "Then you should not take an umbrella" but the thing is it asks twice when I say no
example:

```
Raining? no
Raining? no
Then you should not take an umbrella
```

any ideas how I can make this work ?

I just want to ask you Raining? no and the answer to be Then you should not take an umbrella, not asking you twice and the second time works

Comment: Call `input()` just once, store the value in a variable, and then use that variable in both your `if` statements.

Comment: As said above you can use a variable and check its value, but if you only expect 2 different values using an else statement can also work

Comment: A good case for the walrus operator :=

Answer (score 4):

Ask for the input **before** the `if` statement.

For example:

```
value = input("Raining? ")
if value == "yes":
    print("Then you should take an umbrella")
elif value == "no":
    print("Then you should not take an umbrella")
```

Comment: no need to store before in py 3.8, use the walrus! `if (value := input("Raining? ")) == "yes":` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Just save the input to be compared later.

```
inp = input("Raining? ")
if inp == "yes":
    print("Then you should take an umbrella")
elif inp == "no":
    print("Then you should not take an umbrella ")
```